# What are the detrimental effects of over exercising?

Tags: running, exercise

I am doing the lchf diet and have been increasing my runs everyday to the point that I run about 2 hours plus daily at a 9 minute / km pace. I noticed that my heart rate was a bit elevated in daily runs and that although I was eating close to no carbs daily my weight loss stalled and was even beginning to creep slowly up.

I heard from one of Jimmy Moore's podcast that there are some research that show that over exercising might even slow down or lessen the basal or resting metabolic rate. How true is this ?

Comment: Based on the information presented, it's highly unlikely that you're over-exercising; however, you might not be feeding yourself enough. Before over-exercising begins affecting your body negatively, it would have given you enough warnings. Eat more carbs; **your body desperately needs it for energy.**

Comment: See Michaels answer. If you are running 2 hours a day, you NEED carbs for fuel. Stop following a fad diet, and eat real food, including carbs, the lower the processing involved the better.

Answer (score 5):

Increased cortisol (stress hormone). Elevated heart rate throughout the day. Decreased immune system functioning makes you more susceptible to injury and illness. Decreased metabolic rate. To get into a truly 'overtrained' state is quite hard to do. Make sure you are getting adequate calories and adequate rest if you are going to train that hard long term. And g
et the carbs up. Your body needs them.

Comment: +1 Low carbs are great, unless your training truly requires a lot of them, which at two hours a day you certainly do.

Answer (score 0):

Rest is important for every type of exercise. If you truly mean daily, back off a bit and take 1 to 2 rest days per week. Running like that "everyday" can lead to stress injuries. That is what I would worry about most. Definitely, fuel your body enough to avoid getting weak or dizzy during your runs. Add speed training (i.e. sprints) 1 to 2 times per week to help burn and keep fat away.