# Does over-exercising reduce muscle gain?

Tags: exercise, overtraining

I know that over-exercising can have psychological effects and cause you to become more stressed or get a lack of sleep. However, are there actually any physical disadvantages to over-exercising.

**Will over-exercising affect results when exercising for muscle gain?**

**Will over-exercising deplete your energy levels and render you unable to exercise to your full potential?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does over-exercising reduce muscle gain?
>
> Will over-exercising affect results when exercising for muscle gain?
>
> Will over-exercising deplete your energy levels and render you unable to exercise to your full potential?

Yes.

---

There are a few questions on Fitness.SE that touch on this topic but maybe not from this exact angle. Firstly, [overtraining does exist](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/37222/does-over-training-exist?rq=1). Stressing your body past its point of recovery can be [detrimental](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/22247/what-are-the-detrimental-effects-of-over-exercising?rq=1), however, as the accepted answer points out ***most of us are not overtraining***. The question then becomes: how do I know if I'm training too hard? Which is asked [here](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14285/how-do-i-know-if-im-training-too-hard) and [here](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1547/what-are-some-signs-of-overtraining). Don't confuse over-training with delayed onset muscle soreness. It is OK to [train when you're sore](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/872/is-it-healthy-to-exercise-a-muscle-when-its-still-sore).

From a muscle-gain perspective, you need recovery. The rest time is when your muscles actually do the growing that you're looking for. If you check out the [importance of rest days](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/96/importance-of-rest-days) you'll find a really nice graphic on how rest periods impact muscle growth.

---

Repeated links to questions for easier access:

1. [Does over training exist?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/37222/does-over-training-exist?rq=1)
2. [What are the detrimental effects of over exercising?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/22247/what-are-the-detrimental-effects-of-over-exercising?rq=1)
3. [How do I know if I'm training too hard?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14285/how-do-i-know-if-im-training-too-hard)
4. [What are some signs of overtraining?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1547/what-are-some-signs-of-overtraining)
5. [Is it healthy to exercise a muscle when it's still sore?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/872/is-it-healthy-to-exercise-a-muscle-when-its-still-sore)
6. [Importance of Rest Days](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/96/importance-of-rest-days)

Comment: Those rest day graphics are only based on theory though... They really have no solid evidence of being linked to reality